# How to add more grouping labels to X axis and change the x axis labels size and location?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

I wanna modify my ggplot2 codes with changing the the grouping informaiton on x aixs.

And I have the basic x label named "letters".

But now I need add other two grouping information at x axis named "grouping" and "Disease",respectively.

**My first quesiont is** I know how to add the "grouping" to x axis and modify the rotate angle but I don't know how to change the size and location of xlab "letters" .

**My second question is** I wanna add the second grouping information named "Disease", I don't know how to do with it.
Like this:
[image]
Here is my sample data and code:

```
datt <- data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                  Disease=c(rep("disease1",13),rep("disease2",13)),
                  grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                             rep("Group 2",10),
                             rep("Group 3",6)),
                  letters=LETTERS[1:26])
    head(dat)

##  Without facetting:

ggplot(dat, aes(grouping, value, fill=letters, label = letters)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.8,color="black") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(x=grouping, y=0))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=7))+
  labs(title = "Igfbp7", x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value")
##  rotate_x_text(angle = 45)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the letter labels underneath the x-axis labels?

Comment: @teunbrand  Yes.There are three sets of  information.

letters is the firtst label . But it now overlaps with the  barplot so I  wanna change its location.

The second one is grouping which on the second place. It's in its right location.

Now I wanna add the third label named Disease  and it contains  the grouping .So it should be below the grouping.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use faceting?

Comment: @teunbrand, you authored the `ggh4x` package, right?  Seems like it would be put to good use here for the [nested relations](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/PositionGuides.html#nested-relations-1).

Comment: @chemdork123 yeah that's right, but I couldn't get decent dodging of the letters if they're to be rendered in a `geom_text()`. Using `aes(x = interaction(letters, grouping, disease), ...)` with `guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested())` looks OK, but you don't get the dodging of groups very well.

Comment: Yeah，I know ggh4x now.I think it will solve my problem.