# How to change the label angle in ggh4x package after using scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, ggh4x

Here is my sample data and code 1 ,2 and not perfect 3

```
dat <- data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                  grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                             rep("Group 2",10),
                             rep("Group 3",6)),
                  letters=LETTERS[1:26])
head(dat)

##
dat2 <- data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                   Disease=c(rep("disease1",13),rep("disease2",13)),
                   grouping=c(rep("Group 1",10),
                              rep("Group 2",10),
                              rep("Group 3",6)),
                   letters=LETTERS[1:26])

###  

dat3<-data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                 Disease=c(rep("disease1",13),rep("disease2",13)),
                 grouping=c(rep("Group 1Group 1Group 1",10),
                            rep("Group 2Group 1Group 1",10),
                            rep("Group 3Group 1Group 1",6)),
                 letters=paste0(LETTERS[1:26],"disease&Group"))

value grouping letters
1 9.7119440  Group 1       A
2 0.3838885  Group 1       B
3 7.7584126  Group 1       C
4 7.9419126  Group 1       D
5 3.7792050  Group 1       E
6 5.8977838  Group 1       F

##  ggh4x  1

ggplot(dat, aes(interaction(letters,grouping), value, fill=letters)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.8,color="black") +
#  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(x=grouping, y=0))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=7))+
  labs(title = "Igfbp7", x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested")
##  rotate_x_text(angle = 45) 

#### 2
ggplot(dat2, aes(weave_factors(letters,grouping,Disease), value, fill=letters)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.8,color="black") +
  #  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(x=grouping, y=0))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=10))+
  labs(title = "123", x = NULL, y = "value")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5, 8, 30, 7), "mm"))

##   3
ggplot(dat3, aes(weave_factors(letters,grouping,Disease), value, fill=letters)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.8,color="black") +
  #  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), aes(x=grouping, y=0))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=10))+
  labs(title = "123", x = NULL, y = "value")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5, 8, 30, 7), "mm"))+
  rotate_x_text(angle = 45)
```

I met some problems.

**There are three grouping information that I need to add to the x axis.**

And now I did it using the ggh4x package and the result like this:
[image]

**So I wanna know how to change the angle like the first label.**

Comment: I need help,plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised I've documented quite poorly that there exists a `ggh4x.axis.nesttext` argument to the theme that you can use to control the looks of the text in nested guides. I should perhaps add it to the documentation's examples. Below you'll find an example on how to use it.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

dat3<-data.frame(value=runif(26)*10,
                 Disease=c(rep("disease1",13),rep("disease2",13)),
                 grouping=c(rep("Group 1Group 1Group 1",10),
                            rep("Group 2Group 1Group 1",10),
                            rep("Group 3Group 1Group 1",6)),
                 letters=paste0(LETTERS[1:26],"disease&Group"))

ggplot(dat3, aes(weave_factors(letters,grouping,Disease), value, fill=letters)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",width = 0.8,color="black") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1,size=10))+
  labs(title = "123", x = NULL, y = "value")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = "axis_nested")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5, 8, 30, 7), "mm"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        ggh4x.axis.nesttext.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow , it's what I need now. But I wanna know if I can only change the second or medium label "Group" , but the third one or last one label still  stay horizontal direction？？

And thanks for your help. Because I didn't find the function before as you told me above.

I have the last question:

Could I draw this plot by grouping  using ggh4x package. Just like this: Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3 ????  I really need it .
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887828/how-to-add-more-grouping-labels-to-x-axis-and-change-the-x-axis-labels-size-and

Comment: I haven't bothered making a theme element for each layer of nesting, so no, the lowest labels will be formatted as the second labels. As an alternative, if the second nesting layer has long labels, you can insert a newline character to break the label to two lines. With regards to the dodge-grouping, I couldn't get this to work in a nice way. A workaround would be to encode the position on the x-axis as continuous and then assign labels correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If this package gets the grouping drawing function it will be perfect.

And I used the method you said that use the "\n" . And it works well.